# AngularJS - Change another div's value on click

Tags: angularjs

I have a div as below which calls a controller called WatchlistController .

```
<div class="watchlist_col" ng-controller="WatchlistController">                    
                        <div class="wl_tabs" ng-repeat="my_watchlists in my_watchlist">
                            <a href="" ng-click="get_watchlist_details(my_watchlists.groupid)">{{my_watchlists.groupname}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="watchlists.html"><div class="viewall_wl">View All Watchlists</div></a>
                    </div>
```

Inside the WatchlistController , i have a method get_watchlist_details() which takes the group id as a parameter and returns either 1 , 2 or 3 based on the parameter input . I have tried but the parameter value (my_watchlists.groupid) cannot be fetched by the function get_watchlist_details at all .

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you add you angular function here?

Comment: share ur controller function...